# Format both an expression and its result without eval

Tags: common-lisp, eval

I am trying to format an arbitrary expression, say `(+ 2 3)`, and at the same time, its result, `5`.

I have the following:

```
(defun expr-and-result (expr)
  (format t "~a returns ~a~%" expr (eval expr)))

CL-USER> (expr-and-result '(+ 2 3))
  (+ 2 3) returns 5
```

Though it's a simple matter by using `eval`, I'm curious if this effect can be accomplished without it (because I heard a lot that eval is to be avoided).

I understand that quoting the argument is necessary, because otherwise the given expression will be evaluated as the first step in calling `expr-and-result`, and only its result could be used inside `expr-and-result`. Therefore, any possible solution requires the input to be quoted, right?

I thought a bit about macros but I feel like it's the wrong approach to what I am looking for.

**Edit**: My intent was to construct a simple test-suite, such as:

```
(progn
  (mapcar #'expr-and-result
          '((= (my-remainder 7 3) 1)
            (= (my-remainder 7 3) 2)))
  'end-of-tests)

Outputs: 
(= (MY-REMAINDER 7 3) 1) returns T
(= (MY-REMAINDER 7 3) 2) returns NIL
END-OF-TESTS
```

After reading Paulo's comment, it seems that `eval` is the shortest and cleanest solution for my purposes.

Comment: It depends on how you intend to use this.  If you're developing a verbose debugging macro, then you should generate the `(format ...)` expression, quote the first argument and not the second one.  If this is for the REPL or some interpreter, it's fine.  A compiled alternative to `eval` is ```(funcall (compile nil `(lambda () ,expr)))```, but unless you really want to observe compilation side-effects or perform `expr` several times, there's no need for this.

Comment: @PauloMadeira Thanks for your comment, my intent is to create a concise test suite for comparing function outputs to the expected result. (I edited my question). Generating a `format` expression sounds like overkill, though I feel it will be a more flexible solution than eval.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel: http://cliki.net/test%20framework

Comment: Lots of wheels to choose from!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple macro:

```
(defmacro exec-and-report (form)
  `(format t "~S returns ~S~%" ',form ,form))
(macroexpand '(exec-and-report (+ 1 2)))
==>
(FORMAT T "~S returns ~S~%" '(+ 1 2) (+ 1 2)) ;
T
(exec-and-report (+ 1 2))
==>
(+ 1 2) returns 3
NIL
```

PS. I second @Sylvester's suggestion [not to reinvent the wheel](http://cliki.net/test%20framework)

Comment: I would (personally) probably wrap that in a `LET` and finish with returning the value. That allows for sticking it in as an argument as well (but, hey, this is perfectly fine as-is).